# md-autocomplete with error: Cannot read property 'success' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have used material angular as framework and md-autocomplete, but I receive this error: Cannot read property 'success' of undefined
Here is my code:

```
/*My app.js*/
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute', 'ngMaterial']); //, 'ui.utils.masks'

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', { controller: 'DemoCtrl', templateUrl: 'view/paginaTeste.html' })
        .otherwise({ templateUrl: '404.html' });
});

app.run(function ($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.urlServico = 'http://localhost:58999/';
});


/*My controller*/
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module('app')
        .controller('DemoCtrl', DemoCtrl)
        .config(function ($mdThemingProvider) {
            $mdThemingProvider.theme('default')
                .primaryPalette('blue');
        });;

    function DemoCtrl($timeout, $q) {
        var self = this;

        // list of `state` value/display objects
        self.states = loadAll();
        self.selectedItem = null;
        self.searchText = null;
        self.querySearch = querySearch;

        // ******************************
        // Internal methods
        // ******************************

        /**
         * Search for states... use $timeout to simulate
         * remote dataservice call.
         */
        function querySearch(query) {
            var results = query ? self.states.filter(createFilterFor(query)) : [];
            return results;
        }

        /**
         * Build `states` list of key/value pairs
         */
        function loadAll() {
            var allStates = 'Alabama, Alaska, Arizona, Arkansas, California, Colorado, Connecticut, Delaware,\
              Florida, Georgia, Hawaii, Idaho, Illinois, Indiana, Iowa, Kansas, Kentucky, Louisiana,\
              Maine, Maryland, Massachusetts, Michigan, Minnesota, Mississippi, Missouri, Montana,\
              Nebraska, Nevada, New Hampshire, New Jersey, New Mexico, New York, North Carolina,\
              North Dakota, Ohio, Oklahoma, Oregon, Pennsylvania, Rhode Island, South Carolina,\
              South Dakota, Tennessee, Texas, Utah, Vermont, Virginia, Washington, West Virginia,\
              Wisconsin, Wyoming';

            return allStates.split(/, +/g).map(function (state) {
                return {
                    value: state.toLowerCase(),
                    display: state
                };
            });
        }

        /**
         * Create filter function for a query string
         */
        function createFilterFor(query) {
            var lowercaseQuery = angular.lowercase(query);

            return function filterFn(state) {
                return (state.value.indexOf(lowercaseQuery) === 0);
            };

        }
    }
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.9.0/angular-material.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=RobotoDraft:300,400,500,700,400italic">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1" />
</head>
<body>

    <div layout="column" ng-view></div>

    <!-- Angular Material Dependencies -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-route.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.9.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>

    <script src="/view/app.js"></script>

    <script src="/view/controller/DemoCtrl.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT**
This is my page paginaTeste.html:

```
<md-content>
<form name="frmTeste">
    <section>
        <md-subheader class="md-primary">Novo Teste</md-subheader>
        <md-list layout="column" layout-padding>
            <md-item>
                <md-item-content>
                    <p>The following example demonstrates floating labels being used as a normal form element.</p>
                    <div layout-gt-sm="row">
                        <md-input-container flex>
                            <label>Name</label>
                            <input type="text" />
                        </md-input-container>
                        <md-autocomplete flex
                                         ng-disabled="DemoCtrl.isDisabled"
                                         md-no-cache="DemoCtrl.noCache"
                                         md-search-text="DemoCtrl.searchText"
                                         md-items="item in DemoCtrl.querySearch(ctrl.searchText)"
                                         md-item-text="item.display"
                                         md-floating-label="Favorite state">
                            <span md-highlight-text="DemoCtrl.searchText">{{item.display}}</span>
                        </md-autocomplete>
                    </div>
                </md-item-content>
            </md-item>
        </md-list>
    </section>
</form>
```

I do not know what 's wrong with my code, can anyone help me ?
PS: I'm sorry for my english rsrs

Thank's.

Comment: I'm receiving the same error with my own code.

Comment: Which line is triggering the error?  It should say in your console.  If the error is occuring within material, then use the non-minified versions of their code so we can get a better look at it

Comment: In my console return this error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'success' of undefined" this is line where error occurs angular.js:11655

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you post the code for view/paginaTeste.html?

Comment: Hi @DavidPaquette, thanks for help me. I edited my post above with the code of paginaTeste.html page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem , was the name of the variable that was wrong , so here's my sample code:

**Index**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<div layout="column" ng-view></div>

<!-- Angular Material Dependencies -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-messages.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.9.4/angular-material.min.js"></script>

<script src="/view/app.js"></script>

<!--<script src="/view/angular-material.min.js"></script>-->


<script src="/view/demo-auto-complete/controller/DemoCtrl.js"></script>
```

**App.js**

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute', 'ngMaterial', 'ngMessages']);

    app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', { controller: 'DemoCtrl', controllerAs: 'self', templateUrl: 'view/demo-auto-complete/paginaTeste.html' })
            .otherwise({ templateUrl: '404.html' });
    });

    app.run(function ($rootScope) {
        $rootScope.urlServico = 'http://localhost:58999/';
    });
```

DemoCtrl.js - My controller

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module('app')
        .controller('DemoCtrl', DemoCtrl)
        .config(function ($mdThemingProvider) {
            $mdThemingProvider.theme('default')
                .primaryPalette('blue');
        });;

    function DemoCtrl($timeout, $q) {
        var self = this;

        // list of `state` value/display objects
        self.states = loadAll();
        self.selectedItem = {
            display: 'Alabama',
            value: 'alabama'
        };
        self.searchText = null;
        self.querySearch = querySearch;
        self.clearValue = clearValue;
        self.save = save;
        self.myModel = '';

        function clearValue() {
            self.myModel = undefined;
        };
        function save() {
            alert('Form was valid!');
        };

        // ******************************
        // Internal methods
        // ******************************

        /**
         * Search for states... use $timeout to simulate
         * remote dataservice call.
         */
        function querySearch(query) {
            var results = query ? self.states.filter(createFilterFor(query)) : [];
            return results;
        }

        function findValues (term, obj) {
            var deferred = this.$q.defer();
            deferred.resolve( this.$filter( 'filter' )( obj, term ) );
            return deferred.promise;
        }

        /**
         * Build `states` list of key/value pairs
         */
        function loadAll() {
            var allStates = 'Alabama, Alaska, Arizona, Arkansas, California, Colorado, Connecticut, Delaware,\
              Florida, Georgia, Hawaii, Idaho, Illinois, Indiana, Iowa, Kansas, Kentucky, Louisiana,\
              Maine, Maryland, Massachusetts, Michigan, Minnesota, Mississippi, Missouri, Montana,\
              Nebraska, Nevada, New Hampshire, New Jersey, New Mexico, New York, North Carolina,\
              North Dakota, Ohio, Oklahoma, Oregon, Pennsylvania, Rhode Island, South Carolina,\
              South Dakota, Tennessee, Texas, Utah, Vermont, Virginia, Washington, West Virginia,\
              Wisconsin, Wyoming';

            return allStates.split(/, +/g).map(function (state) {
                return {
                    value: state.toLowerCase(),
                    display: state
                };
            });
        }

        /**
         * Create filter function for a query string
         */
        function createFilterFor(query) {
            var lowercaseQuery = angular.lowercase(query);

            return function filterFn(state) {
                return (state.value.indexOf(lowercaseQuery) === 0);
            };

        }
    }
})();
```

paginaTeste.html - My View

```
<md-content>
    <form ng-submit="$event.preventDefault()" name="frmParceiroNegociosEndereco">
        <section>
            <md-subheader class="md-primary">Novo Endereço</md-subheader>
            <md-list layout="column" layout-padding>
                <md-item>
                    <md-item-content>
                        <p>The following example demonstrates asdasdasda floating labels being used as a normal form element.</p>
                        <div layout-gt-sm="row">
                            <md-input-container flex>
                                <label>Name</label>
                                <input type="text" />
                            </md-input-container>
                        <md-autocomplete flex
                                             md-input-name="autocompleteField"
                                             md-no-cache="self.noCache"
                                             md-selected-item="self.selectedItem"
                                             md-search-text="self.searchText"
                                             md-items="item in self.querySearch(self.searchText)"
                                             md-item-text="item.display"
                                             md-floating-label="Favorite state">
                                <md-item-template>
                                    <span md-highlight-text="self.searchText">{{item.display}}</span>
                                </md-item-template>
                            </md-autocomplete>
                        </div>
                        <h1>Teste</h1>
                    </md-item-content>
                </md-item>
            </md-list>
        </section>
    </form>
</md-content>
```

I have helped someone, and thank you to everyone who helped me.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an error in your md-items binding. Try the following:

```
  md-items="item in DemoCtrl.querySearch(DemoCtrl.searchText)"
```

It also looks like you are binding to DemoCtrl.* but not using the Controller As syntax. Try changing your route definition as follows:

```
{ controller: 'DemoCtrl', controllerAs: 'DemoCtrl', templateUrl: 'view/paginaTeste.html' }
```

Comment: Yes, actually I had an error, but did not work yet, this is error: 

TypeError: Cannot read property 'success' of undefined

Thank's for your help @DavidPaquette

Comment: I added, but still with the same error. I am doing some tests I realized that this error occurs when using the routing system and the ng -view...But do not know why.

Thanks